# Exclude module from compilation in rebar3

Tags: erlang, rebar3

How can I exclude an Erlang module from compilation in rebar3?

It should be included or excluded based on profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a rebar3 profile defining a macro in your rebar.config

```
{profiles, [{nomodulex, [
    {erl_opts, [{d, 'NO_MODX'}]}
    ]}
]}.
```

And in the module add straight after the module declaration
`-ifndef(NO_MODX).`
and in the end
`-endif.`